# How to make IPython run on the python version 3.9.1 instead of the older version 3.7?

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.9

I installed very recently IPython (version 7.19). I installed afterwords python3.9.1 replacing the older version 3.7.1. When I call IPython via the terminal, I always get the indication that IPython is running on the python version 3.7.1.

How to make IPython run on the new version 3.9.1 ?

Comment: I tried it. The main answer of that post did not solve the problem.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. None of the answers on the referred did solve the issue.

Comment: Adding this for posterity: If anyone else is using homebrew on macOS, do NOT use `brew install ipython` - it tends to guess what python version to use, and defaults to 3.8 as of Mar 2021

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following

```
python3.9 -m IPython notebook
```

or

```
py -3.9 -m IPython
```

Comment: I followed your proposal. I get error messages, including invalid syntax.

Comment: did you run from CMD?